# Make an on user visit pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a pop-up window that immediately appears in the middle of the site on user visit https://demo.infyways.com/demo/popup-and-iframes/website-disclaimer-popup

This is an example site of what I want but change the pop-up background. I know that this site is a pop-up generator but whenever I copy the code in generates I get my msg on the top of my site I only want the pop-up when user visits

This is a very mundane example of what I am trying to achieve using query

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js">.  </script>
    <script>
    $( function() {
   $( "#dialog" ).dialog();
  } );
 </script>

<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
 <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying     information. The dialog window can 
 be moved, resized and closed with the      'x' icon.</p>
 </div>
```

I can't seem to remove the close option from it and make it so the user can't proceed if he doesn't accept. I want to create 2 buttons 1 for agreeing -> user proceeds to my site which isn't visible if he doesn't agree 2nd button disagree and there is just a blank page
Can i use query or am I wasting my time for the agree or disagree buttons

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question in your title, and the question you've written are two different things

Comment: @Light Sry for the misunderstanding I want to achieve a result like the 1st link posted, the code is my attempt

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't you just hide the button?

- Either use high-specificity:

> ```css
> .ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
>  display: none;
> }
> ```

- Or force it, using important:

> ```css
> .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
>  display: none !important;
> }
> ```

### Example

```js
$(() => {
  $("#dialog").dialog();
});
```

```css
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-titlebar .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
```

---

#### Update

I would make the window a modal, if you want to grab the user's attention.

```js
$(() => {
  $('#dialog').dialog({
    modal: true,
    dialogClass: 'no-close',
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Accept',
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        // Log the acceptance of aggreement, and continue...
      }
    }, {
      text: 'Decline',
      click: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
        window.location = null; // Take the user somewhere else.
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
.no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<h1>Content Title</h1>
<p>This content isn't accessible, unless you've agreed.</p>
<div id="dialog" title="Attention!">
  <p>This site tracks everything you do.</p>
  <p>Do you accept?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I can't give it as the answer since the most important part of it, is making agree or disagree buttons can I use query for that or am I wasting my time?

Comment: @Philip I addressed this issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery UI API documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/)

> **Hiding the close button**
>
> In some cases, you may want to hide the close button, for instance, if
>   you have a close button in the button pane. The best way to accomplish
>   this is via CSS. As an example, you can define a simple rule, such as:
>
> ```
> .no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
>   display: none;
> }
> ```
>
> Then, you can simply add the no-close class to any dialog in order to
>   hide its close button:
>
> ```
> $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
>   dialogClass: "no-close",   buttons: [
>     {
>       text: "OK",
>       click: function() {
>         $( this ).dialog( "close" );
>       }
>     }
>   ]
> });
> ```

Comment: Chris, can you take another pass at formatting the code? I'd edit myself but I'm not 100% sure of your original intent.

Comment: I read the question as "How do I hide the close button?" As such most of my answer came straight from the jQuery website. I attempted to quote the relevant section and it apparently messed up the formatting. Removed the quote and restored the formatting. :/

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. I've edited to include the quotation.